# How can I read a local file when the user presses a button using the HTML5 File API ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fileapi

I'm trying to use jQuery and the HTML5 File API to get data from a local file. I want to read the file and get text from it, but only when the user presses a button, not when the input field's content changes.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
files = $("#file").files;
var reader  = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var content = event.target.result;
    alert(content);
    agregar(content[0]);
    alert(content);
}
reader.readAsText(files[0]);
```

This code is triggered when the user presses a button on the page. My problem is that when the code runs, `files` is undefined and so I can't get the data I need from it. How can I get the contents of the input file so that I can pass that as a parameter to the `FileReader.readAsText()` function?

Comment: can you post your html? I recently asked a question related to uploading files and then reading the file data with javascript. here is the question. Check my code here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099486/javascript-formdata-via-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `files` array is a property of a `<input type=file>` DOMElement. I don't know how to access it with jQuery, but you can always get the backing DOMElement from a jQuery element using `.get(0)`, so you can access your files here:

```
var files = $('#file').get(0).files;
```

Or with plain javascript:

```
var files = document.getElementById('file').files;
```