# jQueryUI Sortable + HTML5 File API examples?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, fileapi

Does anyone know of any good example(s) which combines jQueryUI:Sortable:display-grid with the HTML5 File API to show dropping multiple local images at the same time into the browser, with all of them then displaying in a display grid?

Ref:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid 
http://html5demos.com/file-api 
[How can I read a local file when the user presses a button using the HTML5 File API ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979464/jquery-reading-files-locally-with-file-api)

Answer (score 2):

Create a placeholder for the images:

```
<ul id="sortable"></ul>
```

Bind sortable to the placeholder:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

Bind the ondrop function to placeholder:

```
$('#sortable').on(
    'drop',
    function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
            if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                upload(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
            }   
        }
    }
);
```

Last but not least, write the File API part:

```
function upload(files){
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        var imageReader = new FileReader();
        imageReader.onload = (function(aFile) {
            return function(e) {
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                li.innerHTML = ['<img class="images" src="', e.target.result,'" title="', aFile.name, '"/>'].join('');
                $('#sortable').append(li);
         };
    })(f);
    imageReader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

See full codes in action at:
http://jsfiddle.net/xKYxL/2/

Credits:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_of_file_api_drag_drop_hard_drive_files_to_a_webpage28?lang=en